# MVC3: Calling a strongly typed helper from custom helper by a dynamic field access

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, strongly-typed-helper

I have strongly typed custom helper (it does nothing - just sample):

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyDisplayFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
{
    return DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(htmlHelper, model => metadata.Model);
}
```

It works great, but I want a make storngly typed helper with strongly typed helpers inside for each property of Model

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyOtherFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, IList<TProperty>>> expression)
{
    ModelMetadata dataModelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, IList<TProperty>>(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    IList<TProperty> modelData = (IList<TProperty>)dataModelMetadata.Model; 
    IEnumerable<ModelMetadata> headModelMetadatas = (new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider()).GetMetadataForProperties(dataModelMetadata.Model, typeof(TProperty))


     foreach (var singleData in modelData)
     {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         foreach(var headModelMetadata in headModelMetadatas)
         {
             sb.Append(
                 DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(htmlHelper, m => singleData ) //this gives me all fields displayed by DisplayFor and I want to access single one per call
                 .ToHtmlString());
         }
     }

}
```

As I mentioned in comment I want to append single fields (this append is simple, there's some more code hidden there which I just cut to make it cleaner) so I tried to get one field at time:

```
DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(htmlHelper, m => singleData.GetType().GetProperty(headModelMetadata.PropertyName))
```

but this gives me just an error. 
Any other good idea, for solving it? ;-)

Edit:

I made some tries and:

```
DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(htmlHelper, m => singleData.GetType().GetProperty(headModelMetadata.PropertyName).GetValue(singleData, null)) still gives an error
```

but:

```
object oValue = singleData.GetType().GetProperty(headModelMetadata.PropertyName).GetValue(singleData, null);
DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(htmlHelper, m => oValue)
```

works! almost as I expected.. It returns display for each property of property. Look at sample of DateTime ;-). More help needed.

Sample, for DateTime:

```
Day
1
DayOfWeek
Thursday
DayOfYear
335
Hour
0
Kind
Unspecified
Millisecond
0
Minute
0
Month
12
Second
0
Ticks
634582944000000000
TimeOfDay
00:00:00
Year
2011
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i just simply returned

```
    MvcHtmlString.Create(oValue.ToString()).toHtmlString();
```

for propertys without using DisplayFor. But more phun started with nested classes and lists.. ;-)

Anyway I solved my problem.